# PHP - parse error when using XML

Tags: php, xml, linux

I have parse error: parse error in /Users/.._1.php on line 4, when-ever i use this following line:

`var labelXml = "<?xml version=1.0 encoding=utf-8?>";`

[image]
[image]

Short open tag was always switched off:

[image]

Comment: can you please try `var labelXml='"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';`?

Comment: Still same problem when i tried with yours.

Comment: Its php parsing error. Its bit strange that its throwing for javascript line.

Comment: YEA - its very strange. i have it same problem in OSX 10.11 and also in RHEL/CentOS 7

Comment: Are you sure screen shot that you have pasted is of `print_1.php`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103789/discussion-between-jimish-gamit-and-yumyumyum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the "< ? ? >" of your var...

I've tested it on my server and i got the same problem

couldn't you use something like this ?

```
var labelXml = "&lt;?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?&gt;";
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Oh my god, how did you do that? its working now. So PHP was screwed?

Comment: This also solved the problem to confuse PHP for its annoying short_open_tag mess: `var labelXml = '<' + '?xml version=1.0 encoding=utf-8?' + '>';` .